# Insert Image into Wordpress child theme hgroup using CSS

Tags: css, image, wordpress, insert, themes

I'm working on a child theme of twentyeleven. I would like to insert a header "banner" image, which includes the company's logo, in addition to the already existing image slideshow in the header area. Since this is Wordpress, I can only do this using CSS (as far as I know, if you know differently please speak up! I know JQuery so that could be an option, but I don't know how to add JQuery to WP.). I've tried a few things: 1) Add a background image to the hgroup div. This doesn't appear to work because the div will not resize to fit the space; the div takes the actual size of the background image. I've also tried 2) insert the image using the :after selector. I'm not sure why this isn't working, but one reason might be that :after (and :before) doesn't support html tags, just text content. Can anyone verify that?

Here is the HTML of the header area, with the hgroup and the slideshow:

```
<header id="branding" role="banner">
  <hgroup>
    <h1 id="site-title"><span><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/" title="" rel="home"></a></span></h1>
    <h2 id="site-description"></h2>
  </hgroup>

  <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/"><img src="" width="1000" height="288" alt="" /></a>
</header>
```

And here is the CSS I've tried:

```
hgroup{
background-image: IMAGE-URL
}
```

Or:

```
hgroup:after{
content: "<img src="IMAGE-URL" alt="header image">";
}
```

If you have any ideas for different approaches to get this done in WP, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: hgroup was recently depricated ;)

Comment: the hgroup element is obsolete in HTML5: http://html5doctor.com/howto-subheadings/

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do much about the markup that WordPress generates. If I were building the thing myself I definitely wouldn't be using the hgroup tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should give **width** and **height** attributes to your tag :

```
hgroup{
    background-image: IMAGE-URL
    width:100%;
    height:120px;
}
```

Nota : *And you should avoid this hgroup tag which has been deprecated.*

Comment: Hi Strategio, Twentyeleven is a fluid theme, so the width resizes with the browser window. Your method doesn't force the image to resize according to the space; the banner image is quite large and runs off the edge when the browser is small. I tried giving the hgroup min and max height and width, but it doesn't affect the background image, only the size of the hgroup. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you're looking for a responsive image block, this won't work with css properties.

Answer (score 0):

Then for a fluid layout, I think the better option for you is to insert an image in your header.

Edit your **header.php** file in your theme (assuming your image is in your theme's "images" subfolder):

```
<header id="branding" role="banner">
  <hgroup>
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/images/my-banner.jpg" id="my-banner" alt="" title="">
    <h1 id="site-title"><span><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/" title="" rel="home"></a></span></h1>
    <h2 id="site-description"></h2>
  </hgroup>
```

Then, for your css :

```
#my-banner {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```